# Format SQL Query Output in Powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I want to format the the output from a sql query that is run in powershell.

The script I have right now is very basic:

```
sqlcmd -S {Server} -d (Database) -b -Q "sp_whoisactive" | format-table
```

Ideally I would like to ensure that the output is in a readable format such as

```
Column 1        Column 2        Column 3
Data            Data2           Data3
```

However right now the data is all over the place and impossible to read and does not include any of the column names.

How I can accomplish this?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting powershell SQL Server output into columns and rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778525/formatting-powershell-sql-server-output-into-columns-and-rows)

Comment: Please provide the code you are using and the result it is returning, then provide how you would **want** it to appear like. This will help us in assisting your needs appropriately.

Comment: Ive updated the description to try to include more info

Answer (score 1):

Powershell does not know how to handle output from `sqlcmd`. Instead use `Invoke-Sqlcmd` which is tailored to the inner workings of Powershell and can pass data as objects which can be manipulated.

If you call `Invoke-Sqlcmd` with a query it will list the results in a linear fashion which is not what you want. To get the format of a tabular view of the data, do *again* as you attempted with the `sqlcmd`...pipe the output into `Format-Table`.

Here is the command to use

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Server '{Server Name}'   '
              -Database {DatabaseName}  '
              -query "Select * from MyTable" | Format-Table
```

Comment: Excellent answer thanks @ΩmegaMan - you might want backticks at the end of each multiline?