# get name of array instead of length powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

Every time I try to export an string or an Array to an CSV, I get not the information from the array. I get the length of the string or of the Array.

For Example:

In Array there is a name called `nbaps111`.

When I do:

```
Export-CSV -Path "C:\Users\admrd\Desktop\test\bat\result_spwo_updated_on.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

I get in Excel `8` but not `NBAPS111`

What am I Doing Wrong? How can I convert it?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534572/export-csv-spits-out-length-only

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
"azerty","toto" | % {New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{"name"=$_} } | Export-Csv C:\temp\t.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

It gives :

```
cat C:\temp\t.csv
"name"
"azerty"
"toto"
```

---

Edited

The pipe part create a `PsObject` object with a property `"name"`, then when you export this object the property apear as the column name. In the default behaviourthe property `"length"` of the type `String` appear in the CSV file.

Comment: Could you explain what the piping does / how it works, please? Thanks!

Comment: @Dropout : I edited my answer this way.